# UDP SocketException - Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: vb.net, sockets, udp

As much as there are many questions on here that are very similar, none of the supplied answers have helped me, which makes me sad :(

I've got a very large management system that I've been tasked to write some UDP packet sending/receiving for. I'd already written a prototype and all was well, so I started merging my code into said system. However, I've now got a (not show-stopping, but annoying) SocketException popping up:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
  ErrorCode=10048
  Message=Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
  NativeErrorCode=10048
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
       at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port, AddressFamily family)
       at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port)
       at Goose.Job.DeviceServerUDPReceiver.InitialiseReceiverClient() in C:\WORK\Trunk\GooseOrders\Classes\SheetCounter\DeviceServerUDPReceiver.vb:line 39
```

Here is the UDPReceiver class - Which is responsible for just sitting in a loop and waiting for responses from the Device Servers we've got dotted about the place.

```
Public Class DeviceServerUDPReceiver : Implements IDisposable
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' CONSTANTS
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Private Const TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_CMD_START As Integer = 0
Private Const TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_CMD_END As Integer = 3
Private Const TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER As String = "_"
Private Const TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_OK As String = "OK"

'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' MEMBER VARIABLES
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Public _ReceivingClient As System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
Public _iReceivingPort As Integer = 2002
Public _thReceivingThread As System.Threading.Thread
Public _bClosing As Boolean

'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' EVENTS
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Public Event GotDeviceResponse(ByVal sResponse As String)
Public Event FoundNewDevice(ByVal TibboObject As TibboDevice)

'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' METHODS
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' Initialises the UDP receiver client on the specified port number. Then runs
' a listening thread constantly waiting to receive udp messages
Public Sub InitialiseReceiverClient()
    Try
        ' TODO - FIX SOCKET EXCEPTION HERE - NOT THREAD ISSUE - THIS IS DUE TO 
        ' THE SOCKET NOT BEING CLOSED. BUT SEEING HOW UDP IS CONNECTIONLESS .... ?!
        _ReceivingClient = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(_iReceivingPort)
        Dim thStartThread As Threading.ThreadStart = New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf SitAndReceive)
        _thReceivingThread = New Threading.Thread(thStartThread)
        _thReceivingThread.IsBackground = True
        _thReceivingThread.Start()
    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception: " & ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try
End Sub

' The endless loop listener thread. Will sit and wait for udp packets to 
' process
Private Sub SitAndReceive()
    Dim epEndPoint As System.Net.IPEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, _iReceivingPort)

    ' infinite loop to listen for udp messages
    While (_bClosing = False)
        Try
            Dim sMessage As String = ""
            Dim byData() As Byte

            byData = _ReceivingClient.Receive(epEndPoint)
            sMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byData)
            Console.WriteLine(sMessage)

            ProcessIncomingUDPDataMessage(sMessage)

        Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While
End Sub

' close the connection to the receiving udp socket
Public Sub Close()
    _bClosing = True
End Sub


' Processes incoming udp packets for answeres from the device servers
Private Sub ProcessIncomingUDPDataMessage(ByVal sMessage As String)

    ' UDP Data packet from Tibbo devices is set out as follows
    '
    ' CMD_ANSWER
    ' Where "CMD" = The command the device is replying too and
    ' "ANSWER" = It's reply
    Select Case sMessage.Substring(TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_CMD_START, TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_CMD_END)
        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_ATO
            '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Any Tibbo's out there reply message 
            '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sMacAddress As String = s(2) ' the replying devices' mac address
            Dim sIpAddress As System.Net.IPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(s(3)) ' ip
            Dim sNetBiosName As String = s(1) ' netbios name
            Dim iTibboStatus As TibboDevice.ETIIBO_DEVICE_STATE = TibboDevice.ETIIBO_DEVICE_STATE.TIBBO_DEVICE_STATE_BAD ' status

            ' set this device status depending on the reply
            If s(4) = TIBBO_DEVICE_REPLY_OK Then
                iTibboStatus = TibboDevice.ETIIBO_DEVICE_STATE.TIBBO_DEVICE_STATE_OK
            End If

            ' create a new tibbo device to pass back to the main form
            Dim Tibbo As TibboDevice = New TibboDevice(sMacAddress, sIpAddress, sNetBiosName, iTibboStatus)
            ' raise event to add this to our list
            RaiseEvent FoundNewDevice(Tibbo)


        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_STS
            '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Status reply message
            '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            ' format our string nicely
            sResult &= "Mac Address: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(1)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "IP Address: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(2)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "Device Name: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(3)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "TiOS FW: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(4)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "Goose SC FW: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(5)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "System Uptime: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(6)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "System Time: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(7)
            sResult &= Environment.NewLine & "System Status: " & vbTab & vbTab & s(8)

            RaiseEvent GotDeviceResponse(sResult)

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_ASC
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Average sheet count message
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            RaiseEvent GotDeviceResponse(sResult)

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_NAM
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Changed device name reply message
            ' Device will reply NAM_[NEWNAME] - once it's set it's new name
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            RaiseEvent GotDeviceResponse(sResult)

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_IDX
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device responds with it's device id
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            ' TODO - do something with the result

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_RBT
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device is going down for a reboot - not much to do here, we have to wait
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_BUZ
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device has played it's buzz sound - ignore
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_FSH
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device flashed it's LEDs - ignore
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_AIP
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device replies with it's actual ip address
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            ' TODO - do something with the result

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_CBC
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device replies with it's current box count
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Dim s() As String = sMessage.Split(TIBBO_MESSAGE_REPLY_DIVIDER)
            Dim sResult As String = ""

            ' TODO - do something with the result

        Case TibboDevice.DEVICE_COMMAND_STP
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ' Device has been stopped - won't reply. Only way to bring it back to life
            ' is to press the 'reset' button on the actual unit - ignore
            '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    End Select

End Sub

Protected Overridable Overloads Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If (disposing) Then
        ' free managed objects
        '_ReceivingClient = Nothing
        _bClosing = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub


End Class
```

Now, all I'm doing in the main form, is: When my listener form is closed - I want to close the listener down (obviously)... For this, I'm using `Dispose()`. However, when someone wants to start it up again, said exception occurs on the `byData = _ReceivingClient.Receive(epEndPoint)` line in the `SitAndReceive` procedure.

Since UDP is transaction based and its sockets (possibly theoretically) can't be in a CLOSE_WAIT state, what is stopping me from closing it down and then immediately relaunching the listener?

I must admit I'm new to UDP sockets, so far however, I've found them a joy to work with and even though this exception wouldn't crash an end-users software (with a simple try/catch), it does have me intrigued and I'd like to understand why it's happening.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Managed to figure this out in the end. Apparently if you want to have more than one connection to a socket, you have to manually configure it, like so:

```
Dim endPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(0, _iReceivingPort)
_ReceivingClient = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient()
_ReceivingClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
_ReceivingClient.Client.SetSocketOption(Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket, Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
 _ReceivingClient.Client.Bind(endPoint)
```

Works now, so I'm happy.

Comment: Nice!  I was having the same issue.  It took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working and I realized I was instantiating my UdpClient object with a port (like `_receiver = new UdpClient(myPort)`), which must do some underlying binding.  After I used the default constructor it worked fine.

Comment: Your solution works just fine! I was sending a multicast request, having multiple receivers on the same host. I was getting the same error when I was trying to run more than one receiver that had to listen to the same port.